# WooCommerce: Own sort/order dropdown (FacetWP)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, facetwp

I want to replace the WooCommerce ordering with the FacetWP sort facet.
To do so, I'm using the output hook `facetwp_sort_options`: https://facetwp.com/documentation/developers/output/facetwp_sort_options/

I have already replaced the order dropdown but the WooCommerce order options are missing.

For now I've only managed to add order by price:

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_sort_options', function( $options, $params ) {

    $options['price_asc'] = array(
        'label' => 'Price: low to high',
        'query_args' => array(
            'meta_key' => '_price',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'ASC'
         )
    );

    $options['price_desc'] = array(
        'label' => 'Price: high to low',
        'query_args' => array(
            'meta_key' => '_price',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC'
         )
    );
    return $options;
```

This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46715264/1788961

But how can I add the rest of the WooCommerce order options.
Is there any list of meta fields I could use?

I need to add the following order options:

- default order
- Sort by popularity
- Sort by average rating

**Edit:** Removed the option for sale products (figured it out myself)

Comment: `_price` or `_regular_price` are price fields.  `SELECT * FROM {yourprefix}_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%price%'`

Comment: Hi, I found that `sale_price` is also a meta field. Or am I wrong?
The problem ist, that the filter sorts by `sale_price` (shows them first) but also shows the products with regular prices at the end. I just want to show sale products.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin facetWP, but it looks like your meta_query doesn't look right as a meta query.  The price fields are `_sale_price, _regular_price, _price`

Comment: The meta query for the price fields (high to low and vice versa) works great. The problem is that I couldn't filter for `_sale_price` alone. It allways shows the products without sale price as well. is there any option to check that in a meta query?

Comment: I found the solution for the sales price check. had to add the following code: `'value' => '', 'compare' => '!='` to the meta query `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Got it from this site](https://dfactory.eu/support/topic/using-with-woocommerce-sort-by-page-view-possible/)

Maybe helpfull:

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_sort_options', function( $options, $params ) {
unset( $options['date_asc'] );
unset( $options['title_asc'] );
unset( $options['title_desc'] );
$options['default']['label'] = 'Standaard sortering';
$options['date_desc']['label'] = 'Sorteren op nieuwste';

$options['popularity_new'] = [
    'label' => 'Sorteer op populariteit',
    'query_args' => [
        'orderby' => 'post_views',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ]
];
$options['price_asc'] = [
    'label' => 'Sorteer op prijs: laag naar hoog',
    'query_args' => [
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '_price',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ]
];
$options['price_desc'] = [
    'label' => 'Sorteer op prijs: hoog naar laag',
    'query_args' => [
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '_price',
        'order' => 'DESC',
    ]
];

return $options;
}, 10, 2 );
```